# How to make default date to avoid weekends in MS Access 2003

Tags: ms-access

[image: Default date]

I have added the default date to be yesterday but I also want it to avoid weekends and show the previous date. Is this possible?

Comment: Creaete a custom VBA function in a standard module, which returns the required date and use it the formula for the default value formula

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom VBA function in the standard module, which returns the required date, like this:

```
Public Function LastWeekDay(dtDate As Date) As Date
    Select Case DatePart("w", dtDate, vbMonday)
        Case 7
            LastWeekDay = dtDate - 2
        Case 1
            LastWeekDay = dtDate - 3
        Case Else
            LastWeekDay = dtDate - 1
    End Select
End Function
```

The function returns yesterday's date or last Friday if yesterday was a weekend day.

And then use it in the default value formula: `LastWeekDay(Date())`

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Sergey's suggestion, you can define a VBA function to branch according to whether the supplied date is a Saturday, Sunday or Monday, subtracting the appropriate number of days.

This could be written as:

```
Function LastWeekday(datRef As Date) As Date
    If Weekday(datRef, vbSaturday) < 4 Then
        LastWeekday = datRef - Weekday(datRef, vbSaturday)
    Else
        LastWeekday = datRef - 1
    End If
End Function
```